# Vector similarity search in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, vector, cosine-similarity, faiss

Is there an implementation of vector similarity search that works in iOS?

I have a set of ~10K+ vectors. When I get a new vector, I'd like to find the top K vectors from the set that are most similar to the new vector.

This can be done either in a loop: compute similarity between every vector in the set and the new vector, and pick the top K.

There are more efficient ways (e.g. [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) or [ScanNN](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/scann)) that can scale to millions of vectors, but they don't work on iOS. Is there an implementation of vector similarity search that works in iOS?

Edit 1:
I've found this project https://github.com/hora-search/hora-ios, but it looks dead. Has anyone tried it out?

Edit 2:
On ~10K vectors, brute forcing works... The question remains open for cases with much more vectors

Answer (score 0):

### Ideas

For me, if the size of vectors to be queried is about 10k+, I'd like to use the brute force query method for it.
Actually, in iOS accelerated framework, there are cblas_ functions(maybe currently marked as deprecated in the API reference).
As the FlatIndex in faiss actually does Gemm and then TopK selection.

I suggest it could be started with cblas_sgemm + heap sort(topk) for a start. In my point of view, on the mobile platform, the power-efficient may be more important, so prefer to call native API from vendors.

### An example poc

```swift
// return random vector with L2 norm
func randFloatArray(dims: Int, count: Int) -> [Float]
{
    var values = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: dims * count)
    for n in 0...count-1
    {
        var sum: Float = 0.0
        let offset = n * dims
        for index in 0...dims-1
        {
            let val = Float(drand48());
            sum += val * val
            values[offset+index] = val
        }
        let sum_sqrt = sqrt(sum)
        for index in 0...dims-1
        {
            values[offset+index] /= sum_sqrt
        }
    }
    return values
}



class Vectors {
    struct QueryResult {
        var v: Float
        var idx: Int64
    }
    var data: [Float]
    var ids: [Int64]
    var dims: Int32
    init (dims: Int) {
        self.data = [Float]()
        self.ids = [Int64]()
        self.dims = Int32(dims)
    }
    
    // heap sort for select top k
    func heapSort(_ array: [QueryResult], topk: Int) -> [QueryResult] {
        var heap = Array(array.prefix(topk))

        func siftDown(_ start: Int, _ end: Int) {
            var root = start
            while root * 2 + 1 <= end {
                let child = root * 2 + 1
                var swap = root
                if heap[swap].v > heap[child].v {
                    swap = child
                }
                if child + 1 <= end && heap[swap].v > heap[child + 1].v {
                    swap = child + 1
                }
                if swap == root {
                    return
                } else {
                    heap.swapAt(root, swap)
                    root = swap
                }
            }
        }

        let count = heap.count
        for i in stride(from: count / 2 - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
            siftDown(i, count - 1)
        }

        for i in stride(from: count, to: array.count, by: 1) {
            if array[i].v > heap[0].v {
                heap[0] = array[i]
                siftDown(0, count - 1)
            }
        }
        return heap.sorted(by:{$0.v > $1.v})
    }
    
    func insert(vec: [Float], ids: [Int64])
    {
        self.data.append(contentsOf: vec)
        self.ids.append(contentsOf: ids)
    }
    
    func count() -> Int
    {
        return data.count / Int(dims)
    }
    
    // query, return (results, gemm time, k select time)
    func query(vec: [Float], topk: Int) -> ([QueryResult], UInt64, UInt64)
    {
        var c = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: Int(self.count()))
        var results = [QueryResult](repeating: QueryResult(v: 0.0, idx: -1), count: Int(self.count()))

        let t0 = UInt64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        
        vec.withUnsafeBufferPointer { vec in
            data.withUnsafeBufferPointer {data in
                c.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {c in
                    cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans, 1, Int32(self.count()), dims, 1.0, vec.baseAddress, dims, data.baseAddress, dims, 0.0, c.baseAddress, Int32(self.count()))
                }
            }
        }

        let t1 = UInt64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        // prepare result before sort
        for index in 0...self.count()-1 {
            results[index] = QueryResult(v:c[index], idx: self.ids[index])
        }
        // sort for poc, using heap sort for tokk is more efficient
        results = heapSort(results, topk: topk)
        let t2 = UInt64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        return (results, t1-t0, t2-t1)
    }
}
```

### Some Benchmarks on iOS devices

with 256 dimensions, input 1 vector query top 3 in 100K records.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your constraints, a vector database like Pinecone could give you what you need.

Comment: In this case, I'm looking for on device vector similarity search, so Pinecone unfortunately can't be used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).